# R says package version different than conda

Tags: r, r-markdown, version, conda

Weird problem and I'm not sure where would be the right place to file an issue.

When I check my package version for `rmarkdown` in R, it says v2.4. However, conda says I have v2.6 installed.

```
C:\Users\ariel>R

R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10) -- "Bunny-Wunnies Freak Out"
Copyright (C) 2020 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.
> packageVersion("rmarkdown")
[1] '2.4'
>
Save workspace image? [y/n/c]: n
C:\Users\ariel>where R
C:\Users\ariel\miniconda3\Scripts\R.exe
C:\Users\ariel>conda list
# packages in environment at C:\Users\ariel\miniconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_r-mutex                  1.0.1               anacondar_1    conda-forge
_tflow_select             2.3.0                     eigen
absl-py                   0.11.0           py38haa244fe_0    conda-forge
aiohttp                   3.7.3            py38h294d835_1    conda-forge
alabaster                 0.7.12                     py_0    conda-forge
...
...
r-rex                     1.2.0             r40h6115d3f_1    conda-forge
r-rlang                   0.4.10            r40h6d2157b_0    conda-forge
r-rmarkdown               2.6               r40hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-roxygen2                7.1.1             r40h796a38f_0    conda-forge
r-rprojroot               2.0.2             r40hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
...
...
...
```

### EDIT:

In my WSL Linux

```
(base) balter@spectre:~$ conda list | grep rmarkdown
r-rmarkdown               2.6               r40hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
(base) balter@spectre:~$ R

R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10) -- "Bunny-Wunnies Freak Out"
Copyright (C) 2020 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-conda-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

current_conda_env: base
current_conda_prefix: /home/balter/conda
no compatible lib
pointing to conda env: base and lib location
[1] "/home/balter/conda/lib/R/library"
> packageVersion("rmarkdown")
[1] ‘2.6’
>
```

### EDIT2:

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "C:/Users/ariel/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.0"
[2] "C:/Users/ariel/miniconda3/Lib/R/library"
```

Comment: In the R session, what does `.libPaths()` output?

Comment: Good catch. See edit. There is another R in 1st place. I could reset `.libPaths` every time I start R, but I'd rather have conda in lead place. I though I took care of that during install.

Comment: I'm going to try just deleting the other R and see what happens. That must have been from before I installed conda.

Comment: One option is to have Conda set the `R_LIBS` environment variable when activating. See  [the docs on setting environment variables](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#setting-environment-variables). Something like, `conda env config vars set R_LIBS="C:/Users/ariel/miniconda3/Lib/R/library"`.

Comment: Minor FYI: `conda list` supports a positional regex argument - no need for `grep`. E.g., `conda list rmarkdown`

Comment: I didn't know you could set environment variables with conda! Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I deleted the other directory and now it works fine!